# Bokeh nested column layout

Tags: python, graph, data-visualization, bokeh

I want to create a nested layout in bokeh with 2 columns. The left column has 2 plots, one above the other. The right column has a number of widgets, all stacked ontop of each other. I also want everything to autofit within the browser window:

[image]

I currently have something like this:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, widgetbox, layout
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput, Button, CheckboxGroup, RadioButtonGroup
from bokeh.plotting import figure

# Set up data
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(time=[1,2,3], acc=[1,2,3]))
source_raw = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(time=[1,2,3], acc=[1,2,3]))

## Top
plot_orig = figure(tools="crosshair,pan,reset,save,wheel_zoom")
line_orig = plot_orig.line('time', 'acc', source=source, line_width=1, line_alpha=1)

## Bottom
plot_new = figure(tools="crosshair,pan,reset,save,wheel_zoom")
line_new = plot_new.line('time', 'acc', source=source, line_width=1, line_alpha=1)

# Set up widgets
sub = TextInput(value="1", title="Option #:")
trial = TextInput(value="1", title="Option #:")

signal_type = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["Raw", "Filtered", "Both"], active=1)
flip_signal_active = []
flip_signal_btn = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Flip signal"], active=flip_signal_active)
filter_order = Slider(title="Filter order", value=2, start=2, end=20, step=1)
filter_threshold = Slider(title="Filter threshold (Hz)", value=10, start=1, end=20, step=1)
reset_options_btn = Button(label="Set Default Options", button_type="danger")

value = Slider(title="Minimum value", value=0.6, start=0, end=1, step=0.01)
distance = Slider(title="Minimum distance", value=30, start=0, end=100, step=0.01)
deletions = TextInput(value="", title="Peaks to delete (comma separated):")
reset_params_btn = Button(label="Set Default Parameters", button_type="danger")
save_params_btn = Button(label="Save Parameters", button_type="success")

# Set up layouts and add to document   
sub_trial = widgetbox(sub, trial)
options = widgetbox(signal_type, flip_signal_btn, filter_order, filter_threshold, reset_options_btn)
parameters = widgetbox(value, distance, deletions, reset_params_btn, save_params_btn)

new_layout = layout([
  column([plot_orig, plot_new], sizing_mode='stretch_both'),
  column([sub_trial, options, parameters], sizing_mode='stretch_both'),
], sizing_mode='stretch_both')

curdoc().add_root(new_layout)
```

That gets me close, as the correct things are stacked on top of each other and the resizing seems to work However, the plots and the widget stack should be in separate columns:

[image]

I tried adding a `row` to split the plots from the widget stack, but everything ends up tiny:

```
new_layout = layout([row(
  column([plot_orig, plot_new], sizing_mode='stretch_both'),
  column([sub_trial, options, parameters], sizing_mode='stretch_both'),
)], sizing_mode='stretch_both')
```

[image]

Comment: Why adding [] and row()/column()in your layout ? Try with layout(row(column(..), column(..))) or just layout([ [up-left, up-right], [bottom-left, bottom-right] ]) [doc](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html#general-grid-layout). Sorry can't test my suggestion right now :/

Comment: the first option doesn't make a difference. And I cant really use the grid type layout suggested in the docs because my layout doesnt fit into a nice grid - the second column doesnt necessarily align with the first column (Ive edited the question to show what I mean)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a way to make the code below work nicely with sizing modes

But if you can afford not to use them, set the figures plot_width and plot_height (e.g. 700x275)
and use a gridplot layout:

```
grid = gridplot([[column([plot_orig, plot_new]),widgetbox(sub_trial.children+options.children+parameters.children)]])

curdoc().add_root(grid)
```

This is the same as column(row(column(),column())) except that you can choose if you want merged toolbars or not
[image]

Comment: thanks but the sizing mode is the most important element. I already have a similar piece of code that can create the correct layout, but Im wanting it to auto fit the window as well

Comment: Sizing_mode is the problem. I also experienced difficulties to make advanced layout that fit to window size. I'm currently back to fixed size layout (with all size regrouped in a single python file to be able to adjust them quickly). I think that some dev has to be done, I will try in future version to come back to stretch_both sizing_mode ...