# Bokeh custom layout

Tags: python, layout, bokeh

My question is similar to the one presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48594862/bokeh-nested-column-layout). I want to create a nested layout with 2 columns in Bokeh:

[image]

However, the right column is filled with other plot types and not just widgets.

I have read about the possible layouts available in [docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/layouts.html), but I wasn't able to achieve the desired result. I've built a minimal example showing one of my approaches:

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange, CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot, row, column, layout

### Main Image
N = 500
x = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
d = np.sin(xx)*np.cos(yy)

p1 = figure(plot_width=640, plot_height=480, x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10),
           tooltips=[("x", "$x"), ("y", "$y"), ("value", "@image")])
p1.image(image=[d], x=0, y=0, dw=10, dh=10, palette="Spectral11")
p1.axis.visible = False

### Bottom histogram
fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
counts = [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6]

p2 = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=200, x_range=fruits, title="Fruit Counts",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")
p2.vbar(x=fruits, top=counts, width=0.9)
p2.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p2.y_range.start = 0

### Right slider
t_slider = Slider(start=0.0, end=1.0, value=1.0, step=.01,
                  title="Threshold", width=140)

### Right image
N = 28
d = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(N, N))
p3 = figure(plot_width=140, plot_height=140, x_range=(0,N), y_range=(0,N), toolbar_location=None, title='Another image')
p3.image(image=[d], x=0, y=0, dw=N, dh=N, palette="Viridis11")
p3.axis.visible = False

l = gridplot([[p1, column(t_slider, p3)],[p3]])
curdoc().add_root(l)
show(l)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was recently a large effort to completely rework layout in Bokeh from the ground up. This work has been merged, but is not yet in a release (it will be the upcoming 1.1 version). When I run your code with `1.1.0dev6`, the results appear to be correct:

[image]

This appears to exactly match the provided layout (if I change the bottom plot to `p2`):

```
l = gridplot([[p1, column(t_slider, p3)],[p2]])
```

So, the current solution is to wait for the 1.1 release.

Note that if you want the bottom histogram to span the whole bottom, you probably want a layout more like this that puts the top/bottom parts in a column:

```
l = column(gridplot([[p1, column(t_slider, p3)]]), p2)
```

which yields:

[image]